# Criteria for Minkowski functionals to induce a complete space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Here is a naïve question: Let $K$ an absorbing, symmetric and convex set of a vector space $X$ that contains 0 that is bounded in the sense that for any direction $x\not=0$, there exists some $n$ such that $nx \not \in K$. Then the Minkowski functional $p_K(x) = \inf \{ \lambda>0: \lambda^{-1} x \in K \}$ defines a norm on $X$.

Is there some criterion that ensures completeness of $X$ with this norm?

Comment: Such sets $K$ whose Minkowski functional is a complete norm are calle *Banach balls* (or sometimes Banach discs). A simple but important condition is compactness in some coarser Hausdorff locally convex topology (this is covered by Parschallen's answer).

Comment: thank you! I just realise, that, with other words, the question was already discussed, for example here :https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56912/can-you-tell-whether-a-space-is-banach-from-the-unit-ball . Without surprise, the answers resemble :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple sufficient condition---that there exists a suitable locally convex topology on the space which is weaker than your norm topology and for which $K$ is complete. This is the Grothendieck completeness theorem.

Comment: What you write is okay (and quite elementary) but I don't think that this is usually called Grothendieck's completeness theorem. There is a theorem of Grothendieck about the completion of a locally convex space (the space of linear functional on the continuous dual with weak$^*$-continuous restrictions to all equi-continuous sets endowed with the topology of uniform convergence on those sets is a completion).